# how to use ssrs using just the sql server2012

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have sql server development studio.I have done  a task using it.but now i am asked to use just the sql server 2012 for it.I have googled but have not got satisfactory results.Most of the posts are about ssrs using visual studio.please guide me.

Comment: what do you want to generate using SSRS in SQL Server? Any user report or Server related info?

Comment: I am very new to ssrs.I should be able to display any report

Comment: SSRS reports are developed in visual studio and deployed to report server   for user access- there is no way of not using VS on the othere hand  Sql scripts developed in sql server management studio can be run from command line sql interactively or in batch mode.

Comment: I have heard about report manager.can it used as an alternative for ssdt.

Comment: It might be worth searching for SSRS course on youtube. SSRS is included in all versions of sql server and consists of a number of elements SSDT - which allows you to graphically design reports and create sql statements to fetch data from your DB and Report Server which is delivers reports via  IE.

Answer (score 0):

The SSRS development tool in SQL Server 2012 is called `SQL Server Data Tool` (SSDT).

While installing SQL Server you will get an option to install `Reporting Services` (This is just the service not Interface for development). To develop SSRS you are required to install `SSDT` (Visual Studio integrated tool) as report development requires a interface. The Reporting Services can be installed with Native mode and SharePoint mode.

In native mode, You will get 2 things called `Report Server` and `Report Manager`, from where you can access your deployed report.

For your knowledge: SSRS report file (.rdl) is nothing but a XML file. If you are expert in writing XML code you can create your RDL file (This is not practically done - not easy).

Search about Report Builder also - It is also client based tool to develop and modify existing SSRS Report.

Comment: k i got it.But I am asked not to use visual studio.what does this mean as you told ssdt is necessary.I am confused

Comment: who asked and why? what are you supposed do develop? Are you looking for a tool for development other than Visual Studio? These are the possible authoring tools for SSRS - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155792(v=sql.110).aspx